# Calculating displacement from acceleration (intuitively)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, integration, calculus

If I say acceleration of car is constant at $4\; \rm m/s^2$.

Then isn’t it that it covers $4\; \rm m$ in $1\; \rm s$ with velocity $4\; \rm m/s$.

Then in $2\; \rm s$, the velocity is $8\; \rm m/s$. Therefore, I (erroneously) conclude it covers $12\; \rm m$.

By crosschecking using the $\Delta d=\dfrac12at^2+ut$ equation with $u =0$, I get:

$$\dfrac12(4)(2\times2) = 8\rm \; m$$

Obviously, my first approach is wrong, but I do not know why. Could someone please explain why my initial intuitive approach failed?

Comment: What you did wrong is you didnt use calculus.

Comment: Trying to do physics without calculus is like trying to run a race on one leg. @user279337

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have constant acceleration, then your velocity vs. time graph will be a linear relationship -- $v(t)=at+v_0$.

The reason your approach doesn't work is because the velocities of $4\;\rm m/s$ and $8\;\rm m/s$ are **instantaneous velocities**. Even though we write "$\rm m/s$", within that one second, the velocity may actually change. So if an object's instantaneous velocity at some time is $4\;\rm m/s$, that **does not** mean that it will travel 4 meters one second later, because half a second later, its velocity could be $40\;\rm m/s$, which means it's no longer travelling at that $4\;\rm m/s$ you assumed.

**If the velocity remains constant**, then it will be true that in after one second, the object travels 4 meters.

However, the presence of acceleration obviously implies no constant velocity.

[image]

(yes, in my sketch I accidentally did displacement between $t=1\;\rm s$ and $t=3\;\rm s$ instead of $t=0\;\rm s$ and $t=2\;\rm s$ as you did, but it's the same concept)

Comment: This is a more useful answer since it actually addresses what the asker misunderstood rather than merely giving a correct framework for thinking. +1 :)

Comment: Thank you (my thoughts exactly :)

Comment: Can I say that at 1.25 second , it’s v will be 5m/s , similarly at t = 1.50,1.75 , v will be 6m/s and 7m/s?

Comment: Yes. The instantaneous velocity for this case is given by $v(t)=at+v_0$ so you can calculate the velocity for any $t$. If you're referring to calculating the velocity using your intuitive method, then yes, that would work too. Because your acceleration is constant, each second, your velocity increases by $a\; \rm m/s$. However, the same approach won't work for displacement, because velocity is **not** constant. What would work is making the intervals very small (i.e. you integrate), but that is a whole new topic.

Comment: Ok.thank you  . @user256872

Answer (score 0):

If your acceleration is constant $a(t) = a$ Then

$v(t) = v_0 + at$ thus $x(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2 + v_0 + x_0$

If your initial velocity and displacement are zero then $x(2) = 8m$

Answer (score 0):

Your intuitive approach was in the right direction. Your mistake was that you used the final velocity after each second to determine the distance, whereas you should have used the average velocity. This is because for each second the velocity is constantly changing e.g. the first second it starts with 0 but gradually increases to 4 m/s

So in the first second the average velocity would be: $\frac{4+0}{2} = 2 m/s$ and the so the distance travelled would be **2m**.

The next second the average velocity would be $\frac{4+8}{2} = 6 m/s$ and the distance travelled would be **6m**

So the total distance travelled is $2m+6m = 8m$